# Pets in Halacha

Tags: product-recommendation, animals

Are there any good books in English that address the basics of keeping pets in Halacha? Obviously one should talk to their rabbi for specifics but at least to know what the discussions are. I see [pets in Halacha](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1946351385)  by R Belsky but it seems to be more theoretical and I’m looking for something more practical.

Comment: There's a journal entry from Rabbi Jachter here http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/english/halacha/jachter_1.htm

Answer (score 2):

Rabbi Natan Slifkin has a full chapter about practical pet care in his work "[Man and Beast: Our Relationships with Animals in Jewish Law and Thought](https://books.google.co.il/books/about/Man_and_Beast.html?id=uOVqKX8PtRMC&source=kp_book_description&redir_esc=y)."

He touches on a number of relevant topics including petting pets on Shabbos, the kashrus of pet food, feeding pets before meals and more.

While a person should always consult with their personal LOR, Rabbi Slifkin does a very good job of raising topics and providing a basic halachic introduction to the issue as well as general halachic guidance.

Comment: Unfortunately it is out of print.